# iPhone : App rejected because "app does not contain sufficient user interactive iOS functionality"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Apple rejected my app and apple gives reason as follow :

```
 "Specifically, we noticed your app does not contain sufficient user interactive
 iOS functionality."

 It would be appropriate to add more user interactive iOS functionality so that
 your app can be appropriate for the App Store."
```

My app contains one `ImageView` and two buttons (next and previous). And I dont need anything else.

I found one link on SO but its [not useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306338/app-rejected-apple-wants-me-to-add-additional-native-ios-functionality)

So what should I do? How can solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like your app can be implemented completely in HTML. If it the experience is no different than that of using a mobile browser, why make an app?

Comment: Sounds like your app just doesn't have enough "stuff" in it for the App store. What does it do, exactly? Shuffle through images you pull down from the web I'm assuming?

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but I don't think this question fits on SO. It's not particularly constructive to the Q&A base, as it's localized and only marginally code related. That said, try integrating your app with Apple technologies. Allow user to Tweet or email the photos. Perhaps add an "about" screen. A slideshow can be servers by a webpage. What makes you app different from that?

Comment: @LoganSerman : It has images which are displayed one by one.

Comment: @awfullyjohn : It does not have any HTML .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it sounds like a subjective reason for rejection, you should look/think about how a user is interacting with your app.  If it is just a *Next/Previous* interaction with static images, this is the same thing as the photo gallery app that comes with the iPhone & iPad.

As a simple suggestion, you could think about linking the image to a web site.  Alternatively, allow your users to add notes to the images.  Both should be fairly easy, and would add functionality for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an app to do this?
Could you make a webpage compatible with ios that way all other devices will have access.

Your answer is simple:

> "It would be appropriate to add more user interactive iOS
>   functionality so that  your app can be appropriate for the App Store."

To be honest I agree with Apple on this one.